# From E-Mail to Lightbox - Help!

Tags: javascript, email, fancybox, lightbox, html-email

Here is my situation - I have a newsletter that I am sending out, what I am attempting to do is when a user clicks a link in the email it redirects to my web page where a lightbox will then pop-up showing a video. I cannot have the lightbox triggered on page load because you can go to the same page and view the content before viewing the lightbox.

Any ideas how to trigger the lightbox from just a link in an email? Is this even possible?

(I am using Fancybox Lightbox)

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Trigger the lightbox via a parameter in the URL that you are not currently using. For example, make the link go to `http://www.mysite.com/page.ext?lightbox=1`. Then, setup a JavaScript that runs on page load and checks if the `lightbox` value is set to `1`, and if so, execute a `click()` event on whatever button normally brings up the lightbox.

Since you are using a new parameter, if someone visits the page normally, they can still view the content without the lightbox immediately popping up because they won't have the `lightbox=1` in the query string.

**EDIT:**

Here is an example of the JavaScript to check the query string. It uses the fancybox on the main page of the site in your profile:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var url = window.location.href;
    url = url.toLowerCase();
    if (url.indexOf('?lightbox=1') != -1 || url.indexOf('&lightbox=1') != -1) {
        $j("#start").fancybox({
            'padding': 0
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Can you give me an example of the JS to check for the 1?  I am unsure how to do that part. - Thanks!